# What is the time complexity of following nested dependent loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
for(int i = 2; i < N; i ++)
    for(int j = 1; j < N; j = j * i)
        sum += 1
```

I got

[image: time complexity]

Can we generalize it further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an algebraic identity about logarithms, logᵢ(N) = log N/log i, so we can take log N out as a factor and the summation is then of 1/log i. Approximating this summation as the integral of 1/log x, we get that asymptotically it is O(N/log N), per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function#Asymptotic_expansion). Since we previously took out a factor of log N, multiplying by this gives a final result of O(N).

Comment: This can be seen without integrals too. Only a minority of the terms (less than sqrt(N) of them) is greater than 2. So this can be bound by 2N + sqrt(N)*logN and the last term is less than N. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes! Thanks! That's another good way! I think we can also show it by making all the terms in the series 1/logn, the addition will be n/logn, which will give O(n).

Comment: If you make all the terms in the series 1/log n instead of 1/log i, then you are making the terms smaller, because log n is bigger than log i - so this doesn't give you an upper bound on the sum.

Comment: Ohh! Yes! my mistake.